# Error in reading 30mb excel file using spark crealytics in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I get the following error when executing the code below.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

[image: Picture]

My code

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("Excel file")
    .getOrCreate()


val dfexcel= spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
    .option("useHeader","true")
    .option("inferSchema","true")
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
    .option("addColorColumns", "False")
    .option("location","files/all_stocks_5yr.xlsx")
    .load("files/all_stocks_5yr.xlsx")
```

Comment: which version of crealytics Api are you using to read excel?

Comment: libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "3.0.1"

Comment: I asked about crealytics API, please use the below one
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.crealytics/spark-excel
libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics" %% "spark-excel" % "0.12.1"

Comment: can you update whether that version helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing related to spark and `com.crealytics.spark.excel` you have to increase your heap memory with eclipse scala ide since its running in local mode.

For example :

[image]

Also I'd recomment to use latest version of creatlytics api

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.crealytics/spark-excel
libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics" %% "spark-excel" % "0.13.1"
```

Comment: was it useful ? you have any questions ?